# How to Configure an Alternate Folder to wwwroot in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible to configure a different folder to replace `wwwroot` in ASP.NET Core? And, if yes, how? And are there any side effects to this change?

The only config that currently includes `wwwroot` in the entire project is found in `project.json` as seen in the code below; but replacing the value with the name of the new folder is not enough for the static file (ex: `index.html`) to be read.

```json
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "web.config"
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is it possible to configure a different folder to replace wwwroot in ASP.NET Core?

Yes. Add a `UseWebRoot` call in your `Program` class:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseWebRoot("myroot") // name it whatever you want
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

> are there any side effects to this change?

Here are three that I can think of:

1. The Bower package manager will not work properly, as it looks for a `lib` folder in `wwwroot`. I'm not certain if this is configurable.
2. You will need to fix `bundleconfig.json` to look at the new directory.
3. You will need to update the `include` portion in `project.json` to include your new directory in the publish output.

Comment: Regarding #1, the path for Bower can be configured in the `.bowerrc` file that should be in the root folder for the project. This is what's there by default: `{ "directory": "wwwroot/lib" }`

Answer (score 14):

With **ASP.NET Core 2.2**, in your `Startup`'s `Configure()` method, you can change the following:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

to

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
  FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
    "myStaticFolder")),
});
```

[Reference / Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2#serve-files-outside-of-web-root) ([auch auf Deutsch](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2#serve-files-outside-of-web-root))

Answer (score 3):

With **ASP.NET Core 6**, if you're using the new [minimal hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model) with the [`WebApplication` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplication?view=aspnetcore-6.0), then the simplest approach is to configure this via the [`WebRootPath` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationoptions.webrootpath?view=aspnetcore-6.0) of the [`WebApplicationOptions` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationoptions?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(
    new WebApplicationOptions() 
    {
        WebRootPath = "mywebroot"
    }
);
```

The minimal hosting model is configured by default in web applications first generated using the Visual Studio 2022+ or .NET 6 SDK templates, so this will likely be the most familiar approach for new ASP.NET Core 6 applications.

While the entry point has changed with `WebApplication`, it’s still technically possible to get to `UseWebRoot()`, as recommended in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40537860/3025856), via the minimal hosting model, but calling it will produce a warning recommending the use of `WebApplicationOptions` instead.